# Let's Encrypt ERR_CERT_INVALID after moving domain to other server

Tags: apache-2.2, https, lets-encrypt, digital-ocean

I run my website on DigitalOcean and due to some problemas I installed a new Ubuntu droplet and moved my website there. After changing my DNS settings for the domain I installed a Let's Encrypt certificate using:

```
certbot --apache -d domain.com.br -d www.domain.com.br
```

All ran through without problems and I got the confirmation that its was installed successfully.

But now when I try to access my website I get: `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID`

1. On my old server I also had a certificate installed
2. I restarted the server already
3. I cleared DNS cache of my browser
4. If I click on the 'not secure' in the URL bar it says INVALID but when I click on details it says VALID

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Check what certificate is served by Apache: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <your_domain_name>:https </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text`

Comment: I have done this. It returns the certificate with a serial number (the same that appears in the browser when trying to access the page)

Comment: Yes, that's expected, but is it valid? Mask the Subject and Subject Alternative Name and add it to your question.

Comment: If I'd have to guess you are connecting to the old server (the old IP is still in your DNS resolver cache) and Let's Encrypt automatically revoked your certificate since you asked for a new one.